# deploy WSO2 DAS into local tomcat server

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

Guys.

i run WSO2 DAS on my local from downloaded source file.

but \i want to deploy WSO2 DAS into my local Tomcat server...\
is there any guide or something?

Thx

Comment: What's the reason for doing that?

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 DAS is an independent product which can run alone. It can not be deployed in Tomcat and there is no use case as such. 
Refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Quick+Start+Guide#QuickStartGuide-Gettingstarted for download and start DAS.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 DAS is not an app that can be deployed into a Tomcat server. WSO2 DAS (and other WSO2 produts) comes as a set of features installed into a vanilla WSO2 Carbon server.

As Tomcat does not support adding features as in WSO2 Carbon there is no way to install WSO2 DAS related features into a Apache Tomcat server.